# How to find whether the text overlaps with the overlay in a PDF

Tags: pdfbox

I am using PDF box version 2.0.25 to manipulate pdf files. I add overlays to the pdf files. These overlays consists of various texts, images and shapes. And I want to check whether they overlap with the existing texts and images of the pdf.

I have found a way to extract the images and text locations of the PDF. But I am unable to find a way to extract overlay information.
Can you please help?

Comment: Isn't an overlay simply the content of some other PDF? In that case determining of *the images and text locations of the PDF* should work also for the overlay. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: I used PDFTextStripper and PDFStreamEngine to get the image and texts. But I can't find a way to get the overlay. overlays have the type PDFormXObject. I don't have a way to differentiate it from other form objects

Comment: Ah, so it's not that you have separate PDFs and want to overlay one over the other (as I thought) but you have one PDF that is the result of prior overlaying, and you now want to analyze whether overlaying created overlaps?

Comment: yes,that's right

Comment: Using form XObjects (`PDFormXObject`) for overlays is quite natural, but you see them used for other purposes, too. If you can be sure that in your case form XObjects only are used for overlays, you can override `showForm` to be informed of whether you are in a form or not.